# getDocument() method of XMLConfiguration of commons-configuration returning null value

Tags: java, xml, apache

I am using `XMLConfiguration` to get DOM Document object from the configuration object as 
given below:

```
XMLConfiguration config = new XMLConfiguration("xml file path");
Document document = config.getDocument();
```

But it is returning null document object .

Am I using right approach?

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't get an exception thrown by `new XMLConfiguration()`, it means that configuration was loaded successfully.

I'm willing to bet that you concluded that it's a "null document object" because you tried to print the value of `document` and got something like:

```
[Document: null]
```

That doesn't mean a "null document".

Comment: Yes ,Issac you are right ! I got this kind of output([Document:null]) when I printed the "document" object . Also , I got "java.lang.NullPointerException" when i tried to print Parent Node using this "document" object using "getParentNode()" method . I am having doubt regarding further use of Document Object which we got from XMLConfiguration . Thanks !!

Comment: I suggest you read the API documentation for the Document Object Model (DOM). Invoking `getParentNode()` on a `Document` instance will always return `null`, because the `Document` instance refers to the XML document as a whole. The reason that the method `getParentNode` exists in `Document` is because `Document` extends `Node` (virtually all important DOM interfaces extend `Node`). It's a somewhat convoluted API but once you get the hang of it, it becomes intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below approach also:

```
File xmlFile = new File("xml file path");  
   DocumentBuilderFactory documentFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory  
     .newInstance();  
   DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentFactory  
     .newDocumentBuilder();  
   Document doc = documentBuilder.parse(xmlFile);
```